# Can we include math symbols?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

In my answer to [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/29/how-can-i-estimate-the-minimum-runway-needed-to-take-off-with-a-hang-glider) I suddenly felt the need to include formula's. I am sorry for this, it is a bad habit of mine, but I am sure it will happen more often.

Is there any way to format those formula's nicely in a way that I have seen for example on the math.stackexchange site?

Comment: Lots of aviation concepts use formulas, so please do turn it on!

Comment: Now that you're in public beta - if you have interest in seeing this enabled, adding an answer here to show cases where it would have been _extremely_ helfpul to have MathJax enabled would be the best way to start.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer is obsolete (this was asked during private beta). There was also another question asked later: http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/145/should-we-use-mathjax-to-typeset-some-equations?lq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not yet.

MathJax isn't added to Stack Exchange sites by default because it significantly slows [page load time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252282/theres-seriously-no-reason-why-latex-markup-via-mathjax-shouldnt-be-enabled-on#204003). Sites can request MathJax once they enter public beta, but they have to make a good case for why their site needs it. Once MathJax is turned on it can't be turned off.

Answer (score 2):

It **is** now possible to include MathJaX:

$$ e=mc^2 $$