# Wierd text when using dollar sign

Tags: bug, formatting

In one case I went to write "about [dollar sign]20 to [dollar sign]25 an hour"  and got weird text in my answer (as you can see below). Apparently having two dollar signs creates some kind of special formatting. This is what it looks like:

about $20 to $25 an hour

Comment: By design; not a bug.

Answer (score 9):

That happens because [mathJax](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/65/609) is enabled on this site, It uses the dollar sign by default.

To avoid getting bitten by this you can escape the \$ using `\$`:

\$20 to \$25